# Как получить участников сервера без добавления бота на сервер с помощью discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты! Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, подсказать возможно ли без добавления бота на сервер с помощью discord.py получить участников этого сервера? Команды и документацию читал, но никак не выходит такое реализовать, поэтому интересно вообще возможно ли такое, или обязательно нужно иметь бота на сервере

Answer (score 0):

Невозможно. Только если бот находится на сервере.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).